# Flyway:info fails with "Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from Datasource"

Tags: sql, maven, flyway

I attempt to run this command below:

```
mvn -Dflyway.user=myusername -Dflyway.password=mypassword -Dflyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://host:port;databaseName=mydbname flyway:info
```

and it fails with:

```
Unable to obtain Jdbc connection from DataSource
Cannot open database "mydbname" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

However the same db login works just fine outside of flyway:

```
sqlcmd -S host -Q "select getdate()" -U myusername -P mypassword -d mydbname
```

Thanks in advance.